# actionmailer formatted from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I want to send emails with formatted sender such as "Support team foo@bar.com".

If delivery method I wrote `from "support team <foo@bar.com>"` and `from "\"support team\" <foo@bar.com>"` but smtp server says

```
#<Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 <support team <foo@bar.com>>: "@" or "." expected after "support"
```

This means that rails puts full "from" string into braces. How can I fix this without monkeypatching?

Comment: What version of Rails? Is it possible you're using one affected by https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2340 / https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3078-actionmailer-233-broke-display-name-support-in-from-address-when-using-smtp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @from         = "\"support team\" <foo@bar.com>"
```

Ref:- [Rails ActionMailer - format sender and recipient name/email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957422/rails-actionmailer-format-sender-and-recipient-name-email-address)

http://jrmehle.com/2009/05/09/setting-email-and-name-with-actionmailer/

OR  TRY

```
From        ["support team <foo@bar.com>"]
```

Comment: I have tried all methods but smtp server already raises the error.