# my company name in the title of email for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rubygems, sendgrid

I'm using a sendgrid gem to send emails with ruby on rails. I need to add the name of the company in the recipient's name. I am using:

```
 mail(
      :from     => "my company name  <info@my_company_name.net>",
      :to       => to,
      :subject  => subject
       )
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You would add the recipients name in exactly the same way you added the fromname.

```
Name <email@address.com>
```

You can see this question for more details:

[Rails ActionMailer - format sender and recipient name/email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957422/rails-actionmailer-format-sender-and-recipient-name-email-address)

Comment: is well "'my company name'  <info@my_company_name.net>"