# Rails - Sending emails with name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send mails with the name of the user in the from address. Something like `"John Doe <john@doe.com>"`. I went through a lot of SO solutions, but still couldn't get this to work.

Here's the mailer:

```
def trigger_email(send_mail, contact, user)
    @mailer = send_mail
    @email = contact.email
    @user = User.find(user)
    mail(to: @email, subject: @mailer.subject, from: "\"#{@user.name}\" <@user.email>")
end
```

I have tried quite a few variants of the above but nothing works. Would appreciate a solution to this issue.

Comment: try some variants from answers for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957422/rails-actionmailer-format-sender-and-recipient-name-email-address

Comment: @SergeySokolov Tried them all. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from:` value in the `mail()` line seems to be wrong. Try:

```
mail(to: @email, subject: @mailer.subject, from: "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>")
```

If that does not work, check with your email provider, maybe they're altering that?