# When I send an email with a comma in the "To" header, the header gets garbled, even though the display name is in quotes. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, postmark

I have a Rails app (rails 4.1.11) using Postmark for email delivery.  I'm trying to include the user's name in the "To" header of my emails, and I'm having trouble in cases where the name contains a comma, even though I'm putting the name in quotes.

I'm generating the "To" header like so:

```
address = Mail::Address.new user.email
address.display_name = user.name
address.format
```

(as suggested in the second answer to [Rails ActionMailer - format sender and recipient name/email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957422/rails-actionmailer-format-sender-and-recipient-name-email-address)).  This automatically puts quotes around the name when necessary, so if the user's name is "Sally Smith, MD" the "To" header will be `"Sally Smith, MD" <sallysmithmd@example.com>`.

However, when the email is delivered, the "To" header is rendered as `"Sally Smith,sallysmithmd@example.com` (at least that's how it shows up in Gmail).  When I look at the raw source of the email in Postmark, I see the expected value, `To: "Sally Smith, MD" <sallysmithmd@example.com>`.  So somewhere between Postmark and Gmail, the header is getting garbled.  Am I doing something wrong when formatting the header?  Is this a Postmark problem?

Comment: Try another test to a non gmail account and see if it's garbled there.

Comment: Just for fun I tried it with an AOL account, and got a slightly different but still garbled header: `"Sally Smith,sallysmithmd@aol.com`

Comment: Actually I miscopied the header from gmail (now fixed).  I get the same garbled header, `"Sally Smith,sallysmithmd@whatever.com`, in both cases.

Comment: Sounds like a Postmark problem then.

Comment: We identified this as a Postmark problem in our back-end. I'm working on a fix now and should have it rolled out shortly.

Comment: Well, that clears that up.  Thanks!